# Running Corda 3.3 in Docker

Tags: docker, corda

I am trying to run my Corda nodes in a docker container, and I am receiving this error message. However, my certificates are present in the container. Has anyone come across this before?

I am able to deploy and run the nodes locally without a problem outside of the docker container.

**Error Message in Docker Container :**

[image]

**Dockerfile :**

[image]

Comment: Please don't use screenshot to share your code but paste it directly in the question using code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, I used openjdk:8u212-jre-alpine in the Dockerfile instead of openjdk:8u151-jre-alpine as the base image.

Answer (score 2):

We recently release the official docker image of Corda 4.4 https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/docker-image.html#official-corda-docker-image

I would suggest you bump your corda version to the latest to have the best experience. There is a lot of changes between Corda 3.x and Corda 4.x